# JBoss FUSE Dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse

I am new to Fuse. I want to develop FTP using camel component. I am using Maven projects and added all camel related jars in dependency. I noticed that JBoss FUSE server also have all camel jars. while packing WAR, all dependency jar will go into WAR's lib folder. if I deploy WAR in FUSE server, what will happen?

1. Don't I need to add jar in lib?
2. Which jar will be used while application runs? ( FUSE jars or Lib jars )
3. Need details about camel dependency in POM.xml
4. It will be helpful if I get sample projects with POM.xml

Comment: JBoss Fuse ships with some examples in the examples directory that is a good idea to study first.

Answer (score 1):

You should set any maven project dependency that Fuse already includes to dependency scope `provided`. This will put them on the compiler class path, but won't include them in the produced War/Jar file.

Comment: I agree this and I need more information about this